# Regular Expression get part of string

Tags: php, regex

How can I get only the text inside "()"
For example from "(en) English" I want only the "en".
I've written this pattern `"/\(.[a-z]+\)/i"` but it also gets the "()";

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = '(en) English';

preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#is', $string, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; # en

?>
```

`$matches[0]` will contain entire matches string, `$matches[1]` will first group, in this case `(.*?)` between `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the dot in your regex good for, I assume its there by mistake.

Second to give you an alternative to the capturing group answer (which is perfectly fine!), here is to soltution using lookbehind and lookahead.

```
(?<=\()[a-z]+(?=\))
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vfng)

The trick here is, those lookarounds do not match the characters inside, they just check if they are there. So those characters are not included in the result.

`(?<=\()` positive look behind assertion, checking for the character `(` before its position

`(?=\)` positive look ahead assertion, checking for the character `(` ahead of its position

Answer (score 0):

That should do the job.

```
"/\(([a-z]+)\)/i"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get `"/\(([a-z]+)\)/i"` and use the capture group to get what you want.

Otherwise, you have to get into look ahead, look behinds

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capture group like everyone else proposes

OR

you can make your match only check if your match is preceded by "(" and followed by ")". It's called Lookahead and lookbehind.

```
"/(?<=\().[a-z]+(?=\))/i"
```